# why my function dont take the global variables?

Tags: javascript

I really don't know why `avanx *= -1` and `avany *= -1` inside *`movimiento`* function don't change the signal of the global variable.

```js
// VARIABLES GLOBALES 
var bola1 = document.getElementById("bola1");
var bola2 = document.getElementById("bola2");

var avancex = 1;
var avancey = 1;
var avancex2 = 1;
var avancey2 = 1;

function movimiento(bola, avanx, avany) {
  bola.setAttribute("cx", parseInt(bola.getAttribute("cx")) + avanx);
  bola.setAttribute("cy", parseInt(bola.getAttribute("cy")) + avany);

  var positionx = parseInt(bola.getAttribute("cx"));
  var positiony = parseInt(bola.getAttribute("cy"));

  if ((positionx + 50) >= 1000 || (positionx + 50) <= 0) {
    avanx *= -1;
  } else if ((positiony + 50) >= 800 || (positiony + 50) <= 0) {
    avany *= -1;
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  movimiento(bola1, avancex, avancey);
  movimiento(bola2, avancex2, avancey2);
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" height="800" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle id="bola1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red"></circle>
<circle id="bola2" cx="700" cy="100" r="50" fill="grey"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: if they're global variables, why do you want to pass them as argument? the code inside the function will have access to them already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is changing the value of a **parameter**, not the global variable itself.

Let me explain that with some more details:

in JavaScript parameters are passed by value, not by reference. When you call  `movimiento(bola1, avancex, avancey)` you are basically **copying** the value of `bola1` (the global variable) inside `bola` (the local parameter) **which is a completely different variable**.

If you modify the parameter (`bola`) inside `movimiento` the changes are made on the parameter itself, which is local copy of `bola1` and therefore changes are not applied to the original one (`bola1`). Remember: in JS, actual parameters and formal parameters are always two different things living at the same time in memory, if you change one **it does not** affect the other one.

**Note about object parameters**

Be careful with objects as they are indeed copied in parameters as normal primitive variables, but they are not cloned. This means actual and formal parameters are still two different variables but they are "*pointers*" referring to the same address, so changing **a property** to one **does** change the other one.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript passes arguments always *by value*. So in effect, you are only modifying a copy of the value that was passed in, not the actual global variable.

You could pass an object with those values as properties and modify the properties that way. Or simply just use the global variables directly (I strongly discourage that however).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 if ((positionx + 50) >= 1000 || (positionx + 50) <= 0) {
        avanx *= -1;
    } else if ((positiony + 50) >= 800 || (positiony + 50) <= 0) {
        avany *= -1;
    }
```

you don't change value of global variable.

try

```js
if ((positionx + 50) >= 1000 || (positionx + 50) <= 0) {
        avancex *= -1;
    } else if ((positiony + 50) >= 800 || (positiony + 50) <= 0) {
        avancey *= -1;
    }
```